# Import date dd/mm from txt to table with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I'm a total beginner and already searched all over the place, so please bear with me.

I have a txt file with this kind of data (DD/MM) and ; as delimiters:

```
01/10;10/06;15/11;10/07
01/10;10/06;15/11;10/07
01/11;20/06;10/11;30/07
01/11;20/06;10/11;30/07
10/11;20/06;20/01;30/07
01/10;01/06;15/11;30/06
```

Firstly, I `set datestyle to European;`

So I have DateStyle - "ISO, DMY".

After, I tried to import this data into some of the columns of the pheno table (see code below), using postgresql:

```
COPY pheno(planting_onset, harvesting_onset, planting_end, harvesting_end) 
FROM '/home/user/Documents/worldcrops/algeria_times.txt' DELIMITERS ';';
```

And gave the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "﻿01/10"
CONTEXT:  COPY pheno, line 1, column planting_onset: "﻿01/10"
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "﻿01/10"
SQL state: 22007
Context: COPY pheno, line 1, column planting_onset: "﻿01/10"
```

Questions: How do I copy this data type DD/MM into a table which columns have date as "data type"? Should I change the columns "data type"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: None of the data in your text file is a **date**. Dates consist of a month, day, and year. You only have two out of three of those. DMY means *D*ay, *M*onth, *Year*, and again you have only two out of three. You can't have a Date type without having a Date to put into it. (This is really a common sense issue, if you think about it.)

Comment: It looks like you have some extra whitespace characters in your CSV file.  Is there any chance you can remove them?

Comment: Agree, Ken White. So should I change the "date type" of the columns to char? And what If I want to calculate the difference between 2 dates within one year (please note that these dates are of any unspecific year)?

Answer (score 0):

It's expecting DMY but you're only giving it days and months. This is kind of hacky but i think it should work:

```
ALTER TABLE pheno 
ADD planting_onset_temp VARCHAR(16), 
    harvesting_onset_temp VARCHAR(16),  
    planting_end_temp VARCHAR(16), 
    harvesting_end_temp VARCHAR(16);
COPY pheno(planting_onset_temp, harvesting_onset_temp, planting_end_temp, harvesting_end_temp) FROM '/home/user/Documents/worldcrops/algeria_times.txt' DELIMITERS ';';
UPDATE pheno 
SET planting_onset   = CONCAT(planting_onset_temp, '/2016'), 
    harvesting_onset = CONCAT(harvesting_onset_temp, '/2016'), 
    planting_end     = CONCAT(planting_end_temp, '/2016'),
    harvesting_end   = CONCAT(harvesting_end_temp, '/2016');
ALTER TABLE pheno DROP COLUMN planting_onset_temp, harvesting_onset_temp, planting_end_temp, harvesting_end_temp;
```

Replace '/2016' with whatever year is relevant.

Comment: thank you @Caius. Despite I didn't use your code to solve the problem, you showed me another possible way that I can use in similar situations. I changed the format to YYYY-MM-DD because it wasn't accepting the DD-MM-YYYY due to the first 0 in DD (eg.: 01/10/2016), and now It can copy to the columns with date type.